# Reading/Write Files From /system

Tags: java, android, file-io

How I can read and write on files from `/system` using Java? I never tried to do anything that required root before, so I don't know how to request permissions for `su` on rooted phones using Java.

*PS: I'm coming from iOS development. Sorry if I'm asking something dumb.*

Answer (score 0):

While I have never tried it, but I believe you are looking for something like [WRITE_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS) which you would place in the manifest xml.

Comment: I think that's just to edit system settings like ringtone and etc.